# Programmatically determining the Bazaar plugin directory

Tags: bazaar

Is there a way to determine the Bazaar directory programmatically?
If there is a bazaar command to determine the plugin directory, this would be the best solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the `Bazaar configuration:` output of `bzr version`.  Also see function `show_version` in `bzrlib/version.py`.

For the configuration directory use:

```
from bzrlib import config
print config.config_dir()
```

Or, for the user plugin path (see `bzrlib/plugin.py`):

```
from bzrlib import plugin
print plugin.get_user_plugin_path()
```

For a full list of plugin paths:

```
from bzrlib import plugin
print plugin.get_standard_plugins_path()
```

Comment: All three answers are correct and its difficult to choose which one is the most correct "answer", but i did need a way to get to the version via the bazaar command rather than the internal api. I didn't mention that i was using java not python to get this directory. 
So I'm going to have to mark this as the anwer :)

Comment: If you need this available as output of bzr command you can write very simple bzr plugin for this.

Comment: Or even just run python with the snippet I've provided.

Comment: I want to install the Bazaar xmloutput plugin when the user installs qbzr-eclipse plugin. So it might not be such a bad idea to run your python script as a Process from java and use the output to determine the path of the user's plugin directory

Answer (score 2):

Bazaar plugins are searched for in the following directories:

```
* <pythonlib>/site-packages/bzrlib/plugins/ 
      (where <pythonlib> is something like usr/lib/python2.4, 
       depending on your installation)

* $HOME/.bazaar/plugins/
```

You can set the bazaar plugins directory via `BZR_PLUGIN_PATH` environement variable, also.

More on bazaar plugins: http://bazaar-vcs.org/BzrPlugins

Answer (score 2):

According to the bazaar [website](http://bazaar-vcs.org/WritingPlugins#advanced-configuration),
user plugins are looked for in `~/.bazaar/plugins` by default, but may be overridden by the environment variable `BZR_PLUGIN_PATH`.
So test if this variable is set, otherwise return the default. In python:

```
import os
user_plugin_path = os.environ.get('BZR_PLUGIN_PATH', '~/.bazaar/plugins')
```

Edit: this works for unix based systems, for windows the uses plugin path is `$APPDATA/bazaar/2.0/plugins`.

The system wide plugin is in `bzrlib/plugins`, see Installing a plugin down the page [here](http://bazaar-vcs.org/BzrPlugins). Use `distutils` to get the prefix (e.g. /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/bzrlib/plugins/) :

```
from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib
global_plugin_path = os.path.join(get_python_lib(), 'bzrlib/plugins')
```

(Thanks to The MYYN for providing the other documentation page)

Answer (score 1):

If you have bzr installed in your system you can use following Python snippet to get the list of directories where bzr looking for plugins:

```
 >>> import os
 >>> from bzrlib import plugin
 >>> list_of_bzr_plugins_paths = [os.path.abspath(p) 
         for p in plugin.get_standard_plugins_path()]
```